# Coloring almost-disjointness

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics

Let $[\omega]^\omega$ denote the collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$. Let $$E = \big\{\{A,B\}: A,B \in [\omega]^\omega \text{ and } |A\cap B| \text{ is finite}\big\}.$$

We consider the graph $G=([\omega]^\omega,E)$. Maximal cliques in $G$, also known as [maximal almost disjoint families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets), are uncountable, and it is consistent that every clique in $G$ has cardinality $< 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Is it consistent that $\chi(G) < 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: What is consistent is that $\mathfrak a<2^{\aleph_0}$ but surely there are MAD families of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, here is one: fix a bijection $f:\omega\to \Bbb Q$ and for every $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ fix a sequence $(q^r_i)$ of rational numbers converging to $r$. Take preimages through $f$ of those sequences and extend to a maximal family to have a MAD family of cardinality continuum.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Since your correction immediately provides a negative answer to the question, it would be good to convert your comment to an answer, so that the software doesn't think the question is unanswered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, $\chi(G)=\mathfrak c$, in fact $G$ contains a complete subgraph on $\mathfrak c$ vertices.

A simple way to construct one is by fixing a bijection $f\colon\Bbb Q\to\omega$ and fixing, for every $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, a sequence $(q^r_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of rationals numbers converging to $r$. Taking the images through $f$ of those sequences gives an almost disjoint family of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ (which can be extended to a mad family of the same cardinality by Zorn's lemma but that's not even needed).

The consistency result is that $\mathfrak a$ can be strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$, that is there can be *some* mad family of cardinality less than continuum.